# Rails 4: Delete session value from API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application `'A'` which runs on iframe of another application `'B'`. I am setting some values on session when the application `'A'` is loaded to iframe of `'B'`. When the users does certain actions of application `'B'`, I want to destroy those session values. So, I created a simple API method which just deletes the session values. Whenever the API to delete session value is called API call is success however the session value doesn't seem to exists in the method.

I used three methods that is supposed to work. But it is not working. The `API::AController` method is:

```
def delete_session_value
   session.key?(:value) # Returns false here
   reset_session # 1
   session[:value] = nil # 2
   session.delete(:value) # 3
end
```

The session is set from `ApplicationController` with simple assignment `session[:value] = 'something'`. The session value is accessible throughout the application. Is the session value not accessible to API controller? Is there any other way I can solve this problem without affecting the flow?

Comment: So `B` calls the API method on `A`? Are you seeing any debug output suggesting a problem? Can you add some `puts` statements to `delete_session_value` to make sure it's actually being called?

Comment: Yeah. It calls API method on A. That is why I mentioned `session.key?(:value) # Returns false here` in the beginning of the method. I used `binding.pry` to verify if it was actually called.

Answer (score 0):

If you session storage is cookie based (which by default, is), then it's a correct behaviour. You cannot read session cookies (or any other cookies) from `iframe`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy.

If this is **same origin request** you could try to set your `x-frame-options`header to `SAMEORIGIN`. https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Yeah. It is cookie based by default. I used `config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
  }` and hoped to read the session. Is there other alternatives?

Comment: `ALLOWALL` does exist but it doesn't let you do anything with cookies from the iFrame, it exists to say that the server is happy for the content to be rendered in an iFrame on any page. It's about whether content is shown, not whether cookies can be accessed.

Comment: @Hbcdev Thank you for pointing this out. Is this recognized by all browsers? (MDN doesn't mention about it). If I understand it right, this option was introduced for [advertising reasons](http://ipsec.pl/web-application-security/2013/mess-x-frame-options-allowall.html)

Comment: @nebula Chrome caches old headers, have you tried disabling cache?

Comment: What it has to do with iFrame? The API is called from another application. And I tried using `Postman - REST Client, chrome extension`, it is working.

Comment: If it's being called from another application, it won't have access to the same cookies / session. I'm only bringing up the iFrame thing because that's what you've done by setting the `X-Frame-Options` header.